# Use multiple `:mode` arguments with use-package

Tags: init-file, use-package

I'm trying out [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) - the docs say the argument to the `:mode` keyword "can be a cons cell, a list, or just a string."  However, I'm not sure how to make a cons cell or list work.  Here's an example:

```
(use-package markdown-mode
  :mode (list "\\.markdown\\'" "\\.md\\'"))
```

With that in my init-file, I get this error:

```
Wrong type argument: listp, list
```

Is that saying a `list` doesn't pass the `listp` test?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The right way to do it would be

```el
(use-package markdown-mode
  :mode ("\\.markdown\\'" "\\.md\\'"))
```

or

```el
(use-package markdown-mode
  :mode (("\\.markdown\\'" . markdown-mode)
         ("\\.md\\'"       . markdown-mode)))
```

---

In general, to see what any macro is expanding to, take the cursor to the closing parenthesis of that macro and do `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`.

Comment: And realize that macros do not evaluate their arguments (by default).